# In iOS Detect whether user removed his app from Facebook via app settings or changed password

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-login

I am using `FBSession.activeSession.state` to check if user is logged in to Facebook or not.

```
+ (BOOL)isLogin
{
return (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen||FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended);
}
```

But from this we can't find out whether user has removed the app from Facebook settings or changed the password. Can we get to know if current access token is valid or not.

Facebook has this guidelines for the login test:

```
If Someone removes your app from Facebook via app settings and revisits your app,
Your app should detect this and prompt the person to log back in.
```

Is there any other way to find this out?

Comment: Well, you would store the access token. If, when returning the access token on next startup of app, it is nil - you know the app was previously removed.

Comment: How to get updated access token every time the app is started? should I call Fabacebook login every time

Comment: I'm sure you have it stored in NSUserDefaults. Then just return the stored token.

Comment: In Facebook sdk 3.x access token stored and handled automatically by the FBSession.

Comment: so when I call FBSession's  `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:` , It is not giving error even if I changed the password of facebook.

Comment: Is it not left up to the FBSession to also check for an access token then?

Comment: It should check and give error but I am not getting error in completion handler.

Comment: I am getting session closed error only if I call any `FBRequest` not at `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graph API to check if token is still eligible. Documentation is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors